# Refactoring common static methods in java

Tags: java, refactoring, static-methods

Consider:

```
class C1 {
    public static void doWork() {
        // code fragment F1
        doMoreWork();
        // code fragment F2
    }
    private static void doMoreWork() {
        // code fragment F3
    }
}
class C2 {
    public static void doWork() {
        // code fragment F1
        doMoreWork();
        // code fragment F2
    }
    private static void doMoreWork() {
        // code fragment F4
    }
}
```

Note that `doMoreWork` in `C1` and `C2` have different code, but the code in
`doWork()` in `C1` and `C2` are identical.

How can this class structure be refactored so that calls to `C1.doWork()` and `C2.doWork()` behave as above but the code for `doWork()` is not duplicated?

**Edit:** Please note that the methods must be static after refactoring.
Also, fragments F1 and F2 are really code fragments with possibly one or more open context---e.g. fragment F1 opens a "{" and the closing "}" is in fragment F2.

Comment: Please note in your question that you want to keep methods `static`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another class `C` that contains the code you don't want to duplicate.

```
class C {
    public static void f1() { /* code fragment F1 */ }
    public static void f2() { /* code fragment F2 */ }
}
```

Then you can call `C`'s methods from `C1` and `C2`.

```
class C1 {
    public static void doWork() {
        C.f1();
        doMoreWork();
        C.f2();
    }
    private static void doMoreWork() {
        // code fragment F3
    }
}
class C2 {
    public static void doWork() {
        C.f1();
        doMoreWork();
        C.f2();
    }
    private static void doMoreWork() {
        // code fragment F4
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "different context".  I don't know what your code really looks like.  All I see is F1 and F2 to pull out to a different class so code isn't copied.

Comment: But all you have in your post is `// code fragment F1` and `// code fragment F2`.  Perhaps your post oversimplifies your actual problem.

Comment: If there is state common to both F1 and F2, then F1 will need to return that state, and F2 will need to accept that state as parameter(s).

Comment: Thank you, I added a clarifying comment at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you want to keep both methods static, complicates the problem significantly. I even doubt it can be done that way.

Why do you insist on keeping things static? 
Usually, there is no reason to keep things static, as you can easily convert from a "static" context to a non-static context by creating a new instance.
So instead of

```
C1.doWork();
```

you just do

```
new C1().doWork();
```

If you don't mind using non-static methods, you could do something like this:

```
class C {
        public void doWork() {
            // code fragment F1
            doMoreWork();
            // code fragment F2
        }

        protected abstract void doMoreWork();
}

class C1 extends C {
        protected void doMoreWork() {
            // code fragment F3
        }
}

class C2 extends C {
        protected void doMoreWork() {
            // code fragment F4
        }
}
```

This is just sketchy, I didn't even try if it compiles.